# How To Downgrade From Stretch To Jessie

Tags: upgrade

I've given up on Stretch, I'm getting issue after issue with it. How do I downgrade to Jessie?

Comment: For a downgrade you probably need to reinstall

Answer (score 2):

There is no established method for downgrading from testing or unstable to stable, and there likely never will be. See these two posts on the Debian wiki [here](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianStability) and [here](https://wiki.debian.org/SystemDowngrade). Your best course of action is to back up any important data and reinstall Debian.